# Можно ли добавить уже готовые графики plotly.express в plotly.subplots

Tags: plotly

Есть три графика сделанных в plotly.express.

```
fig1=px.line(...)
fig2=px.bar(...)
fig3=pxbar(...)
```

Мануал по plotly.express вроде говорит, что px возвращает plotly.graph_objects.**Figure**

Можно ли каким-то образом вставить эти три готовые фигуры в sublots после

```
fig = make_subplots(rows=3)
```

?

Т.е. не прибегая к построению графиков заново через fig.add_scatter / fig.add_bar и т.д.?
А просто добавить уже готовые графики в sublots?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: можно добавить отдельно линии (trace) из существующего графика px.express на subplots. Можно объединить датафреймы, задать признак разделения и по новому признаку разделить на facet.

Comment: А вообще, проще самому с помощью go собрать какие угодно графики

Comment: наверно если бы мне было проще в go, я бы и не спрашивал про plotly.express. но так получилось, что мне совсем не проще разбираться в построении одного графика трема абзацами кода

Comment: Ну раз вам проще через px.express, то конечно соберите свой subplots перекинув их из px.express... только вот незадача, так сделать нельзя... так что походу не проще, потому что невозможно. а проще либо через go, либо объединить датафреймы, задать признак разделения и по новому признаку разделить на facet.

Comment: как выяснилось - вполне можно. но из всего интернета помочь с этой (как выяснилось в процессе) малюсенькой проблемой смог только chat gpt, который продемонстрировал, что из уже готового графика plotly.express можно просто извлечь бОльшую часть данных и впихнуть в sublot`ы.

конечно полностью избежать разборок с graphic objects не получится, но в части именно построения графиков, можно обойтись именно plotly.express. и только для наведения красоты разбираться с update_layout и прочими радостями.

Comment: да уж...читать вы явно не умеете, первый мой комментарий как раз об этом... забрать trace можно, запихнуть полностью готовый график нельзя...